# How is this topological space different from the euclidean one?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm preparing for my topology exam and came across this example which I can't figure out.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a such family of all sets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ that $U\cap L$ is an open set in L, for L- any line parallel to X, or Y-axis with topology induced by the euclidean metric.

I know that this space is different from the Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's not even a metric space, but I can't show why. Can anyone give me an example of a set open in one space but not open in the other?

**Edit:**

In the meantime I think I've found the example:

Let $A=\lbrace (x,y): |x|,|y|<1, (x=y\iff x,y\leq 0)\rbrace$. Then $A$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$ but it's not in euclidean topology.

Comment: When you say open set in $L$ do you mean open in the subspace topology induced by the euclidean metric or?

Comment: Also when you say *a line parallel to either X or Y-axis* do you mean it has to be open for every line parallel to the x-axis xor to every line parallel to the y-axis, meaning just one axis at a time, or both axes at the same time?

Comment: 1. yes, topology induced by the euclidean metric on that line

Comment: 2. I mean: $L$ is a line which is parallel to X-axis or Y-axis, it doesn't matter which one of them (it's obvious it can't be parallel to both)

Sorry for my lack of precision, if you can think of any better wording for what I want to say, tell me.

Comment: The issue actually lies with what an open set is, do you mean for every horizontal xor every vertical line $U \cap L$ is open or for every horizontal or vertical line $U \cap L$ is open? It's a subtle difference but very important

Comment: 'or'. I've editted, pleas check if it's clear now

Comment: Your example works.